# Release a viewController correctly that sets it self as delegate to other classes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

First thing i do is create a ViewController and push it to the Navigation Controller.

```
viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[navController pushViewController:viewController animated: NO];
[viewController release];
```

Retain count is 2 now (pushViewController uses 2 retain apparently but not my responsibility) so far so fine.

Inside MyViewController i'm createing a instance of a class and sets the ViewController as delegate to the instance.

```
timer = [[MyBackgroundTimer alloc] initWithInterval:20];
[timer setDelegate:self];
```

Now the viewControllers retain count has increased by 1 becouse of setDelegate:

But when i'm releasing the viewController later it will never call dealloc becouse i have one more retain count.

How should you correctly drop the retain count when you set your self as delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `MyBackgroundTimer` should have the delegate property as assign and not retain.

```
@property (nonatomic, assing) id delegate;
```

And this class should retain the delegate just when it needs to use it, and release when it is done.

```
@implementation MyBackgroundTimer 

@synthesize delegate;

-(void) startTimer {

    [self.delegate retain];

    //... do some actions

}


-(void) timerStopped {

    //... call delegate methods

    [self.delegate release]

}

@end
```

It is important to remember that you **can** have your delegate as a retain property. But to do so the right way, you have to ensure that you release it before dealloc is called (like the `timerStopped` method in the example above)

I say that because if you try to release the delegate at the dealloc method, the class that instantiates `MyBackgroundTimer` is the same class as the delegate, and it also releases `MyBackgroundTimer` at the dealloc (which is pretty much the common case), the dealloc method of both classes will never be called, as each class will have the ownership of the other, resulting in a memory leak (that will **not** be shown at instruments).

Comment: You shouldn't retain your delegates. When `MyViewController` is preparing to dealloc, it should either release `MyBackgroundTimer` or set the delegate of `MyBackgroundTimer` to nil.

Comment: did even read the answer? thats what I said in 'Your class MyBackgroundTimer should have the delegate property as assign and not retain.'... do you know what assign means?

Comment: … and then you go on to say, "this class should retain the delegate…" Was I misreading your answer?

Comment: Yes, you were... "And this class should retain the delegate JUST WHEN IT NEEDS TO USE IT (...) But to do so the right way, you have to ensure that you release it before dealloc is called"... thats what is described in the basic chapter of memory management guidelines... cmon man, read the hole answer before downvoting...

Comment: At best retaining your delegate is unnecessary, at worst you'll get a circular reference and leak both objects. Where in the memory management guidelines does it say you need to retain a delegate before messaging it?

Comment: What happens when `MyViewController` tries to release `MyBackgroundTimer` while the background timer is retaining `MyViewController`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't retain your delegate. If you're using a property, define your delegate as assign, not retain. Somebody else needs to retain your delegate, not you.